# Не запускается сервлет

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, tomcat

Здравствуйте, есть пример из книги Head first Servlets and JSP, который не получается запустить.

web.xml (Путь: webapps\ch1\WEB-INF)

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”ISO-8859-1”?>
<web-app xmlns=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee”
xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”
xsi:schemaLocation=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd”
version=”2.4”>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Chapter1Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Ch1Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Chapter1Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Serv1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Ch1Servlet.class (Путь: webapps\ch1\WEB-INF\classes)

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Ch1Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                  HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    out.println("<html> " +
                "<body>" +
                "<h1 align=center>HF\'s Chapter1 Servlet</h1>"
                + "<br>" + today + 
                "</body>" +
                "</html>");
    }
}
```

URL в браузере: http://localhost:8080/ch1/Serv1

> Нет связи с сайтом
>   Хост localhost отклонил запрос на соединение.
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tomcat нормально запускается, стандартные примеры тоже. В чем беда?

Comment: Извиняюсь, по адресу http://localhost:8080/ tomcat запускается, а HelloWorld стандартный не отображает, выскакивает тоже сообщение в браузере

Comment: Путь: webapps\ch1\WEB-INF\classes. Этот путь должен быть в папке с Tomcat. Он у вас есть?

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - это обычно сетевая ошибка. Скорей всего до сервера приложений запрос даже не доходит. Или этот сервис даже не запущен. Если сервер работает, то в худшем случае написал бы ошибку протокола HTTP: ресурс не найден,  внутренняя ошибка сервера, и т.п.

Comment: @Владимир, этот путь есть в папке. Tomcat настроил нормально, теперь вылазит 404( Что я не так делаю?

Comment: @Игорь Горбунов Нужно вначале создать проект и скомпилировать его . Получится Ch1Servlet.class. Вот теперь создаем папки в Tomcat и копируем Ch1Servlet.class в WEB-INF/classes, а web.xml в папку WEB-INF. Структура папок должна быть, как на картинке в книге.

Comment: @Владимир, спасибо за ответ, в книге был устаревший пример. Со своей стороны я все делал правильно. Ответ нашел, когда начал набирать web.xml в IntelliJ IDEA - она подсказала, как правильно